# I want to change the UIButton Highlight Image, but without success

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIbutton in my view

### I want to change the UIButton Highlight Image, but without success

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 66, 29)];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_down_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(filterAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];


- (void)filterAction:(UIButton *)button
{
    if(button.isSelected == YES)
    {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        button.selected = NO;
    }
    else
    {
#warning I want to change the UIButton Highlight Image, but without success
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_down_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        button.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain more in detail about what you want?

Comment: your link shows error

Comment: That link isn't even appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by without success? Explain in detail

Comment: do you want pressing state image highlighted

Answer (score 1):

If you want your button to behave as follows,

normal - filter_button_normal
highlighted (on touch press down on button) - filter_button__down_selected
selected (after removing touch from button) - filter_button_selected;

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter_button_down_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

so when the user touches it , image changes to highlighted and when he removes his finger over it, it changes to selected

And the target you added is UIControlEventTouchUpInside

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(filterAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

so  filterAction is called after the user removes his finger from it.

```
- (void)filterAction:(UIButton *)button
{
// the image will change automatically
    if(button.isSelected == YES)
    {
        button.selected = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        button.selected = YES;
    }
}
```